# TextButton LibGDX only clicks once

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm coding a libGDX application that uses a button. The button looks like this:

```
TextButton btnPrint = new TextButton( "Print", skin );
btnPrint.setClickListener( new ClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void click(Actor actor,float x,float y )
    {
        System.out.println("Printing...");

    }
} );
```

When I click the button, it prints"Printing..." as expected, however, if I click it again, it does nothing. How can I fix that?

Comment: Im not sure that this will fix your problem but may try using on "OnClickListener" instead?

Comment: Is this your literal code? There is no `setClickListener` method in any libgdx class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Out of my head but try:

```
btnPrint.addListener(new ClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y)
    {
        System.out.println("Printing...");
    }
});
```

Everything used here comes from the LibGDX library so import the correct classes. Perhaps you are using `vis-ui`, `AWT`, `JavaFX` or anything else? I find it mysterious that your code is compiling correctly.

Comment: This works perfectly, exactly what I needed! Thanks a bunch

Comment: @JordanGoulet You are welcome, if you should accept this answer and earn 2 rep for that ;).